# Java - How to automatically update value on JLabel?

Tags: java, swing

I have a slot machine that deductes 3 credits after every spin. I have a JLabel created which currently displays "Credits: ". I was wondering is there a way to do "Credits: %d, credits" which will update the value displayed on the JLabel?

Comment: You'd simply change the text on the JLabel when the credits value changes by calling its `setText(...)` method. Where are you stuck?

Comment: Im just not sure how to update a text value on the JLabel. I have just set the text on the Label by using credits = new JLabel(" CREDITS:");. I dont know how to add a way to edit the value of credits so that it updates automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You state:

> I dont know how to add a way to edit the value of credits so that it updates automatically.

Nothing updates "automatically" -- you have to write code for it to update pure and simple. Fortunately that code is nothing more than calling `setText(...)` on your JLabel. So you could do this when you change the value of your credits, or if you need to make a larger more complex MVC program, use a listener system to notify you when values change and then call `credits.setText(...)`.

e.g.,

```
updateCredits() {
   creditValue -= 3;
   String text = String.format("Credits: %d, credits", creditValue);
   creditLabel.setText(text);
}
```

Comment: So would i be able to do this? 'myCredits.setText("%d",credits);' Where cash is a value that i update after every spin?

Comment: @user1232112: yes, but the devil is always in the details, including the details of how your program is set up, things we have no knowledge of.

Answer (score 0):

As already stated above, you should add a piece of code that updates the value of your JLabel wherever you deduct the credits.(For example in the ActionEvent of your spin button.)

It would look something like this:

```
credits.setText("CREDITS: " + noOfCredits + " credits");
```